# UICollectionViewFlowLayout, UICollectionView: changing screen orientation breaks cells arrangement

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit

```
let numberOfCellsPerRow: CGFloat = 3

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0

    collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height), collectionViewLayout: layout)
    collectionView.backgroundColor = .clear
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")

    view.addSubview(collectionView)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 3
}

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let cellWidth = (view.frame.width - max(0, numberOfCellsPerRow - 1) * layout.minimumInteritemSpacing) / numberOfCellsPerRow

    return CGSize(width: cellWidth, height: 75.0)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let itemCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    itemCell.backgroundColor = .black

    return itemCell
}
```

Vertical Orientation
[image: Vertical Orientation]

Horizontal Orientation
[image: Horizontal Orientation]

I'm expecting all cells on the same row. Why there is some margin on the left side of the first cell (horizontal orientation)? In the case when I'm launching the application with horizontal orientation, some space appears between cells in vertical orientation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use auto-layout

```
self.collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

    self.collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor),
    self.collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor),
    self.collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor),
    self.collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor),

])
```

Or refresh the frame inside `viewWillTransition`

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {

    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

    self.collectionView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)

    self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()

}
```